# storing non English character to mysql database

Tags: spring, model-view-controller

Technologies used in Applcation is listed below.

Spring MVC Version 4.1.6.RELEASE
Hibernate Version 4.3.5.Final
MySQL 6.0.11
My JSP is configured with

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=UTF-8" pageEncoding="UTF-8"%>
```

And

```
<meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8">
```

Hibernate configuration is

```
<prop key="hibernate.connection.useUnicode">true</prop>
```

UTF-8
UTF-8

MySQL URL is

```
jdbc:mysql://host:port/dbName?useUnicode=true&connectionCollation=utf8_general_ci&characterSetResults=utf8
```

Pojo having String field to store that data.

MySQL have VARCHAR datatype to store data with charset=utf8 and Collation=utf8_general_ci

When i tried to save any non-english character it show some garbage character like ?????? for "مرحبا".

Is there any other configuration which I missed here?

Answer (score 0):

Probably try to use NVARCHAR column datatype instead of VARCHAR

Comment: NVARCHAR is not listing in my mysql database

Comment: This datatype exists in mysql from 5.5 to 8 versions (https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/charset-national.html). Maybe it is defined with another name.